# Cannot pass data with jquery ajax to php through post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I use this code, which was taken by another post of stackoverflow, but one part was not working for me.

```
<script>

// variable to hold request
var request;

// bind to the submit event of our form
$("#notification").submit(function(event){

// prevent default posting of form
event.preventDefault();

// abort any pending request
if (request) {
    request.abort();
}

// let's select and cache all the fields
var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

// let's disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
$inputs.prop("disabled", true);

//this code was added by me cause i saw that when i pass as data {notTitle:"smth"} 
//it works, so i wanted to remake that structure and include all my elements.
// Apparently it does not work, maybe because i create a string and by 
//{notTitle:"smth"}, notTitle is not passed as string.
 x=$("form").serializeArray();
 var str="{";
 var size = x.length;
 $.each(x, function(i, field){
    if (field.value!="")
     str = str.concat(field.name + ":" + field.value);
   else
     str = str.concat(field.name + ":" + "k");
   if(i!=size-1)
     str=str.concat(",");
 });

str=str.concat("}");

// fire off the request to /form.php
request = $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: str//{notTitle:"s",notType:''}
});


// callback handler that will be called on success
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    alert(response.status);
});

// callback handler that will be called on failure
request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    // log the error to the console
    alert(
        "The following error occured: "+
        textStatus, errorThrown
    );
});

// callback handler that will be called regardless
// if the request failed or succeeded
request.always(function () {
    // reenable the inputs
    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
});


});

</script>
```

And here is my php

```
<?php $result = array("status" => "1",  "a" => "2");
$notificationTitle = htmlspecialchars($_POST["notTitle"],ENT_QUOTES,'ISO-8859-1');
echo json_encode($result); ?>
```

Before you suggest the use of serializing the form, I tried it and it does not work. What I noticed is that when I try to pass data to my php file, I cannot read them through $_POST['name of element']. So if I comment the second line of the php file and pass as data {notTitle:'s'} it works and I see the successful message.

Comment: have used `jQuery.serialize()` with php for years and never had a problem...sure seems like you are reinventing the wheel

Comment: Why are you POSTing JSON instead of normal POST data, then not reading/decoding the raw post data on the PHP side?

Comment: I am not posting JSON, this is the response from the server, if i understood your point correctly. So i am trying to pass normal data.